# Toggle table - increase rowspan to accommodate extra toggled row

Tags: jquery, css, css-tables

I have a table that can be toggled fine with a button or by clicking on the row. The problem is when the 1st column is spanned over 2 or more rows everything goes out of sync. Also would like the bottom border to move under the toggled area and the hovered area background colour to line up with additional rows (currently only works with 1st row because of the rowspan). Hopefully this makes sense and someone can help with this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $(".toggle").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function() {
    $(".toggle").show();
  });
  $("#data tr td").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".pointer").next().toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

table,
th {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 10px;
}

tr:hover td {
    background: #e5e5e5;
}

.toggle {
  display: none;
}

.toggle.active {
  display: table-row;
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="hide">Hide All</button>
<button id="show">Show All</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header</th>
    <th>header</th>
    <th>header</th>
    <th>header</th>
    <th>header</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="data">
  <tr class="pointer">
      <td style="border-bottom:1px solid;" >DATA1</td>
      <td style="border-bottom:1px solid;">data1</td>
      <td style="border-bottom:1px solid;">data1</td>
      <td style="border-bottom:1px solid;">data1</td>
      <td style="border-bottom:1px solid;">data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="4">toggled area 1a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pointer">
      <td  style="border-bottom:1px solid;" rowspan="2">DATA2</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="4">toggled area 2a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pointer">
      <td style="border-bottom:1px solid;">data2</td>
      <td style="border-bottom:1px solid;">data2</td>
      <td style="border-bottom:1px solid;">data2</td>
      <td style="border-bottom:1px solid;">data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="4">toggled area 2b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pointer">
      <td rowspan="3">DATA3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="4">toggled area 3a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pointer">
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
     <td></td>
      <td colspan="4">toggled area 3b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pointer">
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="4">toggled area 3c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First wrap each data area in a `<tbody>`.
- All `tr.toggle` should have **only one `<td>`** and it should have `colspan='4'`
- Only the first `<td>` of each `<tbody>` has the class `.pointer` and a `rowspan` equal to the number of initially visible rows of said `<tbody>`. **ex.** *first `<tbody>` has one row initially so `td.pointer` in that `<tbody>` has a `rowspan='1'`*.
- When a `<td>` other than a `<td>` nested within a `tr.toggle` is clicked and is now visible, the corresponding `.pointer` `rowspan` increases by 1.
- `.pointer` `rowspan` decreases by 1 when a `tr.toggle` is not visible.
- The last `<tr>` of data area 1 and 2 has an unclickable `<td colspan='5'>` which contains a `<hr>`.

```js
$("#all").on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('show hide');
  toggleRow(e);
});

$('.pointer').on('click', toggleRow);
$("td").not('.toggle > td').on('click', toggleRow);

function toggleRow(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('td')) {
    var toggle = $(this).parent().next('.toggle');
    var data = $(this).closest('tbody');
    var pointer = data.find('.pointer');
    var rowspan = Number(pointer.attr('rowspan'));
    toggle.toggle();
    if (toggle.is(':visible')) {
      pointer.prop('rowspan', `${rowspan+=1}`);
      if (e.target.matches('.borderA')) {
        data.find('.borderA').css('border-width', '0');
      }
    } else {
      pointer.prop('rowspan', `${rowspan-=1}`);
      if (e.target.matches('.borderA')) {
        data.find('.borderA').css('border-width', '1px');
      }
    }
  } else if (e.target.matches('#all')) {
    $('tbody').each(function() {
      var pointer = $(this).find('.pointer');
      var rows = $(this).children().length;
      var rowspan = Number(pointer.attr('rowspan'));
      if ($('#all').hasClass('hide')) {
        $('.toggle').show();
        pointer.attr('rowspan', rows);
        $(this).find('.borderA').css('border-width', '0');
      } else {
        $('.toggle').hide();
        pointer.attr('rowspan', rowspan);
        $(this).find('.borderA').css('border-width', '1px');
      }
    });
  }
  return false;
};
```

```css
table {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table,
th {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

tr:hover td,
tbody:hover .pointer {
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

.toggle {
  display: none;
  text-align: center
}

.pointer {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.border,
.borderA {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

#all {
  width: 10ch;
}

#all.hide::before {
  content: 'Hide ';
}

#all.show::before {
  content: 'Show ';
}
```

```html
<button id="all" class='show'>All</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="pointer show" rowspan='1'>DATA1</th>
      <td class='borderA'>data1</td>
      <td class='borderA'>data1</td>
      <td class='borderA'>data1</td>
      <td class='borderA'>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
      <td class='border' colspan="4">1A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class='pointer show' rowspan="2">DATA2</th>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
      <td colspan="4">2A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='borderA'>data2</td>
      <td class='borderA'>data2</td>
      <td class='borderA'>data2</td>
      <td class='borderA'>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
      <td class='border' colspan="4">2B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="pointer show" rowspan="3">DATA3</th>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
      <td colspan="4">3A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
      <td colspan="4">3B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='borderA'>data3</td>
      <td class='borderA'>data3</td>
      <td class='borderA'>data3</td>
      <td class='borderA'>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
      <td class='border' colspan="4">3C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The table gets messed up when clicking hide all/show all. Is it not possible to use the border-bottom instead of <hr>? Also would like when hovering over table row the 1st column background is also highlighted to indicate it is the same section, at the moment only the first row highlights and not the second or third.

Comment: that works well, except the pointer & toggle are incorrect and should only show & toggle only on data rows, not the 1st column. Sorry didn't realise this would be so complex

Comment: So if the pointer is clicked all rows of that data area toggle? Ex. DATA 3 is clicked so 3A, 3B, and 3C are toggled?

Comment: No, jut one row is toggled at a time. The hide/show all is correct and toggles all. The first column should not have a pointer or toggle, but should expand when rows are toggled. There should also be bottom border under 1st column.

Comment: Ok, this is tight as a drum, check it out (you;ll probably want to add padding).